# How can I get real time script error notification when using a google sheets onOpen() function that errors out?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I can see the 'failure' and 'paused' errors when I view stackdrive-logging. I would like a notification, similar to a Browser.msgBox() when any error occurs in the script, so that i can then check the stackdriver-logger for details. I do not need any details, just a simple pop-up notification while working in the spread sheet. I looked at adding a Trigger, but can not making sense of how to implement an [on-ERROR].

Comment: So easy when you know how.  Try..Catch is absolutely what I needed. It's now in my 'tool box' .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have **onOpen** function code such as below:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var x = 1 / y; // initial code with possible error
}
```

We can and should handle possible errors by [`try .. catch`](https://javascript.info/try-catch) block. Error object e1 contains useful error description, you might want to display it as alert. So the code should be like this one:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  try {
    var x = 1 / y; // initial code with possible error
  } catch(e1) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(e1.message);
  } 
}
```

Really it shows alert box with error description after spreadsheet open.